# Imagine 2014 displaying images with large no-data values

Tags: image, erdas-imagine, display

I'm starting to use Imagine 2014 after a recent upgrade.  The images I'm using have data values in the range of approximately -.02 to 350.0.  The no-data values bordering the data has a value of 2 billion. The data displays white, nan black.  It was easy to limit the values considered for generating a lookup table for display in previous versions but I'm not finding the tools now.  What is the best way to  get this data to display legibly in Imagine 2014?

Thanks.